# Profiling query using Performance Schema on RDS Aurora MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-performance, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to profile a query that takes 40 seconds to run on my RDS Aurora MySQL with activated performance schema. I was hoping I can get a complete breakdown on where the execution time was spent using queries to `events_statements_history_long`, `events_stages_history_long` and `events_waits_history_long` tables.

I've activated everything in `setup_instruments` & `setup_consumers` tables just to get as much data as possible in the beginning. I've also updated `threads` table to have only my user thread being monitored.

The `events_statements_history_long` table says that the total duration of my query was 40.658176 seconds but when I try to summarize time using `events_stages_history_long` & `events_waits_history_long` tables using provided `event_id` I only get 1.4 and 0.001 seconds respectively. So I have no visibility into what it was doing the remaining 39 seconds. If that time was spent on sending data back to the client I assume it would be captured in `events_stages_history_long` table.

*events_statements_history_long*

```
SELECT
  EVENT_ID,
  TRUNCATE(TIMER_WAIT / 1000000000000, 6) AS Duration,
  SQL_TEXT
FROM performance_schema.events_statements_history_long
WHERE SQL_TEXT LIKE '%UNIQUE_THING%';
```

[image: events_statements_history_long output]
*events_stages_history_long*

```
SELECT
    sum(TRUNCATE(TIMER_WAIT / 1000000000000, 6)) AS total
FROM performance_schema.events_stages_history_long
WHERE NESTING_EVENT_ID = 13348585;
```

[image: events_stages_history_long output]

*events_waits_history_long*

```
SELECT sum(TRUNCATE(TIMER_WAIT / 1000000000000, 6)) AS total
FROM performance_schema.events_waits_history_long
WHERE NESTING_EVENT_ID = 13348585;
```

[image: events_waits_history_long output]

Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: I'm cynical about getting much useful info from the 'stages'.  Would you care to show us the query, its `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Speeding it up may be as simple as adding a composite index.  (And nothing in the stages will say that!)

Comment: @RickJames With this question I wanted to make sure I'm using "stages profiling" correctly. I have some ideas on what to do with my query and I hoped profiling with stages would be a reliable way to see if things are getting better. Based on your reply I deduce it's not. It's quite a big chunk of execution time that is simply untraceable in my case.

Comment: Look at my answers to other mysql performance questions.  Often I can point at a subquery, or `IN`, or lack of `INDEX`, etc., as the reason for a slow query.  After changing that, the execution time gets suddenly faster.  Meanwhile, any profile/explain/optimizer-trace/etc also changes radically.